# Graphing Tangent Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to graph the problem y=tan3θ-1 and then find the amplitude, period, phase shift, vertical shift, and domain and range. I have found everything except the domain. There is a vertical asymptote line at π/6. the domain for tangent functions is θ≠nπ/2, where n is an odd integer. My question is what would be the domain for this problem? How would I go from π/6 to nπ/2? My teacher didn't go over this, so please help if you are willing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned that a domain is the first interval in which you have a continuous function. For tan(\theta) that is -pi/2 to pi/2. However I have heard people say that tan(theta) is defined over all values excluding +- ((2n+1)pi)/2. Remember words are only words, you have to understand what the word implies in your context.